# How to serve the external jsp, not in WEB-INF/views, in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

In the origin old system, there is a JSP file which is generated dynamically in WEB-INF/views and have the following configurations in spring-mvc.xml.

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/downloadAppPage" view-name="downloadAppPage" />
<!-- mvc view -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/views/" p:suffix=".jsp" p:contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

But now, I change the original system by the Spring Boot loading and with the embedded tomcat startup (jar -jar *.war). And the downloadAppPage will not be accessed anymore.

So is it possible to configure or code the Application to serve the external JSP files outside of the Spring Boot context path?

Thanks,
James.

Comment: do you means downloadAppPage in inside /WEB-INF/views path ?

Comment: if you migrate to spring-boot why do not use thymeleaf in the view side? will be easier and more consistent

Comment: @BhushanUniyal, the original downloadAppPage was in /WEB-INF/views and it was generated dynamically. For now the fat jar don't have such paths.

Comment: @cralfaro It is a legacy project, but I can try thymeleaf.

Comment: @James.Y I just tell you that because its very easy to migrate, and fast, also you will have a more consistent and stable project

Comment: @James.Y, hopefully I'm not too late. You can add other beans of type view resolver to the configuration; you can even right your own view resolver, it's fast and easy

Answer (score 0):

You can add other beans of type view resolver to the configuration, adding your external folder. They will be processed in the order you put them in the configuration. You can write, as well, your own view resolver.

```
public class MyViewResolver extends InternalResourceViewResolver {
@Override
protected AbstractUrlBasedView buildView(String viewName) throws Exception {
    HttpServletRequest request=((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
    String viewFile =request.getRealPath(this.getPrefix()+viewName+this.getSuffix());
    File reqFile=new File(viewFile);
    System.out.println(reqFile.getAbsolutePath()+":exists:"+reqFile.exists());
    if(!reqFile.exists()){
        viewName="default";
    }
    InternalResourceView view = (InternalResourceView) super.buildView(viewName);
    view.setAlwaysInclude(false);
    return view;
}
}
 // example extracted from https://javabeat.net/extending-viewresolver-and-chaining-viewresolvers-in-spring-mvc/
```

And then, your configuration file would look like:

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/downloadAppPage" view-name="downloadAppPage" />
<!-- mvc view -->
<bean class="mypack.MyViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/your/new/path/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        <property name="order" value="0" />
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        <property name="order" value="1" />
</bean>
```